# simple user_exists function using PDO connect to mysql

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm still in the early learning stages, banging my head against walls looking for clues. Iv been reading the manual to no avail.

I'm building a user log in system based on the phpAcadamy tutorial 'Register & Login' (part 5-2). They use `mysql_connect()` in the tutorial, but I am using a `PDO` connection for mysql.

I am making my first function, `user_exists()`, which `returns` a `true` or `false` depending on if the username is in the database.
it queries for the `user_id` (an auto-incremented value in the db) when `username` = the POSTed `$username` then depending if the `user_id == 1`, returns a `true` or `false`.

here is my testing code: 
the if statement at the bottom should test the function above it.

> i get a Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

```
    <?php

    $host       = "localhost";
    $username   = "mholberg_skroovy";
    $password   = "omitted";
    $dbname     = "mholberg_skroovytest";


$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};", $username, $password);


function user_exists($username) {
    $query = $db->query("SELECT `users`.`user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return(mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;                //???
}



if (user_exists('junkomatic') === true) {
    echo 'exists';
}
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring your connection object (`$db`) into the function's scope.

Here's an example

```
function user_exists(PDO $db, $username) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    return (bool) $stmt->fetchColumn();
}

$host       = "localhost";
$username   = "mholberg_skroovy";
$password   = "omitted";
$dbname     = "mholberg_skroovytest";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8",
    $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (user_exists($db, 'junkomatic')) {
    echo 'exists';
}
```

Comment: is the ? in line 2 literally supposed to be a ? its still not echoing exists, i just get a blank page. it does exist though!

Comment: Yes, it's a statement parameter placeholder. Does that username exist?

Comment: yes, its in the username column of the users table of that db. it has a user_id of 1

Comment: and i know its connecting fine because i can get other basic queries to print from it.

Comment: oh! i must have missed the execution of the prepared query! works now. THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: @mholberger Yeah, sorry about that. I missed it the first time too ;)